# Open a spreadsheet with broken formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, c#

I am using code the generate a spreadsheet, including a formula for a cell on certain rows. When I do this, there is something wrong with the formula, and when I try and open the spreadsheet, Excel asks if it should repair the sheet. If I say yes, it does this by removing all traces of my formula from the sheet. If I say no, it doesn't finish opening the sheet.

Is there a way I can open the spreadsheet without the repair, so I can examine the formula as it is generated by my code. If I copy and paste the formula into one of the cells it was removed from, it works fine. I really need to see what is wrong with the formula in my generated sheet when I open it. Is there any way of doing this?

I am adding the formula using the code below on the EPPlus Excel library:

```
for (var r = startAt + 2; r < endAt; r++)
{
    var amountFormula =
        $@"=SWITCH(C{r}; ISBLANK(D{r}); """"; ""Percentage""; IF(ISNUMBER(D{r}); D{r}; 0) * IF(ISNUMBER(E{r}); E{r}; 0) / 100; IF(ISNUMBER(D{r}); D{r}; 0) * IF(ISNUMBER(E{r}); E{r}; 0))";
    ws.Cells[$"F{r}"].Formula = amountFormula;
}
```

Please note that this formula works if I replace `{r}` with a proper row number and paste the formula into the sheet.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share the code you are using so far, help us to understand and fix it !!

Comment: @RajeshS I have asked more technically on StackOverflow what might be wrong with my code. In this question, I only wish to know how to open a workbook without formulas being removed. I want them still there so I can debug them.

Comment: You've already try both of your options, I don't think you can do more to open your corrupted sheet. A workaround can be to insert your formula as text (`ws.Cells[$"F{r}"].Value = amountFormula;`), open your worksheet and check how your formula look like.

Comment: Thanks, @MátéJuhász, that sounds like an excellent idea. Maybe even post it as an answer.

Comment: @ProfK,, the code you have used is not VBA (macro) code, used with Excel,, but it's C programming ,, please [Edit] your post & modify TAG will soon draw attention of C Program users !!

Comment: @RajeshS It's C# programming, and you asked for code. I have no VBA code, I create the sheet with C# code.

Comment: @ProfK,, since TAG with your question simply indicates that you have stuck with any VBA code,, now as soon you posted the used code,, it's clear that your need is different,, that's the reason I've suggested you to [Edit] your post and add `C Program` TAG !!

Answer (score 0):

> Excel asks if it should repair the sheet. If I say yes, it does this by removing all traces of my formula from the sheet. If I say no, it doesn't finish opening the sheet.

I think you've tried all your options here.

A workaround can be to insert your formula in the cell as text (`ws.Cells[$"F{r}"].Value = amountFormula;`), then you'll be able to open your sheet and examine your formula.

(If Excel still complain on your formula, you can even add a preceding `'`: `ws.Cells[$"F{r}"].Value = "'" & amountFormula;`)